# QMediaRecorder does not record anything

Tags: c++, mingw, qt-creator, webcam, video-capture

I have a program that records video from a web camera. It shows the camera view in the form. When start button clicked it should start recording video and should be stopped after pressing stop button. Program compiles fine but no video is recorded. Can anyone say what is the wrong with it? 
Here is my code.

```
 {      
            camera = new QCamera(this);
            viewFinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
            camera->setViewfinder(viewFinder);
            recorder = new QMediaRecorder(camera,this);

            QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
            layout->addWidget(viewFinder);
            ui->widget->setLayout(layout);

            QVideoEncoderSettings settings = recorder->videoSettings();

            settings.setResolution(640,480);
            settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::VeryHighQuality);
            settings.setFrameRate(30.0);
            //settings.setCodec("video/mp4");

            recorder->setVideoSettings(settings);
            recorder->setContainerFormat("mp4");
            camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
            camera->start();
       }

        void usbrecorder::on_btn_Record_clicked()
        {                
            usbrecorder::startRecording();
        }

        void usbrecorder::on_btn_Stop_clicked()
        {
            usbrecorder::stopRecording();
        }


        void usbrecorder::startRecording()
        {              

            recorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\Stranger\\Downloads\\Video\\vidoe_001.mp4"));
            recorder->record();
        }

        void usbrecorder::stopRecording()
        {
            recorder->stop();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to limitations on Windows.

As mentioned in Qt documentation here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html#limitations

> Video recording is currently not supported. Additionally, the DirectShow plugin does not support any low-level video functionality such as monitoring video frames being played or recorded using QVideoProbe or related classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an output location:

```
QMediaRecorder::setOutputLocation(const QUrl& location)
```

e.g.

`setOutputLocation(QUrl("file:///home/user/vid.mp4"));`

Comment: I have specified the path as recorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\Stranger\\Downloads\\Video\\vidoe_001.mp4"));
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the state, status and error message:

```
qDebug()<<record.state();
qDebug()<<record.status();
qDebug()<<record.error();
```

and see what it prints. With those messages you can have a clear picture of your problem. Maybe QMediaRecorder cannot access your camera.